# index.php shows up in url

Tags: urls

I run two websites on apache2 on ubuntu, site roots are in /var/www/site1/html and /var/www/site2/html.
The url structure of both of them is like this: example.com/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

When I change it in wordpress settings, I get the apache2 404 page, not the wordpress 404 template, everywhere except at the frontpage. wp-admin still works, because in its url, there isn't index.php.

mod_rewrite is enabled, I edited the .htaccess file, and also tried adding this:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

to the .htaccess file, but the error still persists.

Also, if I set the url settings to plain (example.com/?p=123), it works, there's no index.php in it.

At this point I have no idea what can cause it, I can only think of database, or file permission errors, every idea is welcome.

The settings that I want to work:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4gu3.png
The settings with which I dont get 404:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7K93.png

Comment: When you go to the front page, what URL do you see? Do you see only http://example.com or do you see http://example.com/index.php?

Comment: I see example.com

Comment: Thanks. If this is still a problem it might be helpful for others here to see what your Permalink settings are. Can I suggest you take a screenshot of the Permalink settings page in your dashboard and add it to your question?

Comment: Of course, done.

Answer (score 0):

After making any changes like this, always go to the Dashboard Settings > Permalinks and then click save.